# Setting Buffer from GeoprocessingTools with a feature

Tags: qgis-3, buffer, pyqgis-3

I'm trying to set up a Buffer from Geoprocessing Tools and i would like to put a Field from the layer as Distance Souce.

Here is my code :

```
import processing
layer =  QgsVectorLayer(path_to_routes, 'Routes', "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
processing.run('native:buffer', {"INPUT": layer, "DISTANCE":50, "OUTPUT": memory:buffer})
```

I don't find a solution to put a field on "DISTANCE" parameter.

Here is a picture of what i want to set up.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference an existing field in a parameter, you could use:

```
QgsProperty.fromExpression('"fieldName"')
```

So your code would look like:

```
import processing
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path_to_routes, 'Routes', "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
processing.run('native:buffer', {"INPUT": layer, "DISTANCE":QgsProperty.fromExpression('"fieldName"'), "OUTPUT": 'memory:buffer'})
```

Comment: Cool, I went with `layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex('DISTANCE')`, but it did not work. `QgsProperty.fromExpression` instead works on a feature per feature basis.

Comment: Again, thank you @Joseph, i used .fromExpression but not with QgsProperty classe. Thanks !

Comment: @RafDouglas - Good to know, thanks for your comment :)

Comment: @ValentinL. - Most welcome! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there :)

### GUI option

Use the "Assistant" option:

[image]

then:

- Select the field you want to use as a buffer distance
- Elick on the reload icon to see the data range
- Enter the same min-max values in the fields below `Output from` and `to`

[image]

### PyQGIS

Expanding on Joseph's answer:

```
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsProject,
    QgsProperty
)
import processing

input = "/tmp/QGIS3-6iz04U/temp.shp"
layer = QgsVectorLayer(input,"polygon","ogr")

processing.run("native:buffer", {
    'INPUT': layer,
    'DISTANCE': QgsProperty.fromExpression('"DISTANCE"'),
    'SEGMENTS': 10,
    'DISSOLVE': False,
    'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
    'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
    'MITER_LIMIT': 10,
    'OUTPUT': '/tmp/QGIS3-6iz04U/buffers.shp'})
blayer = QgsVectorLayer('/tmp/QGIS3-6iz04U/buffers.shp',"buf","ogr")    
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(blayer)
```

Comment: I don't understand how i'm supposed to connect this to my code ? I fail to my explanations. What i want is put on "DISTANCE" paramater in the processing.run not 50 like in my code but a field like 'ID' which create the buffer with this feature.