# Creating different numbers of random points inside polygons using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, point-in-polygon, random, point-creation

I am developing a plugin using PyQGIS and PyQt5. I am calling `qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons`, where I am trying to give field input at `VALUE` parameter. It will take a variable number of points for each polygon in the layer. But somehow it is not using field for the same. Attaching the code snippet for the reference.

```py
padding_op.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("vlp1_num", QVariant.Double)])
padding_op.updateFields()

padding_op.startEditing()

for f in padding_op.getFeatures():
    aval_a = (float(f["final_a"])*perc)/100
    vlp1_size = a*b
    f["vlp1_num"] = int(aval_a/vlp1_size)
    padding_op.updateFeature(f)

padding_op.commitChanges() 

num = padding_op.fields().indexFromName('vlp1_num')

random_parameters = {'INPUT':padding_op,
                     'STRATEGY':0,
                     'VALUE':num,
                     'OUTPUT':'memory:'}
random = processing.run('qgis:randompointsinsidepolygons', random_parameters)
random_op = random['OUTPUT']
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(random_op)
```

Here, the number of points to be created in each polygon is stored in `vlp1_num` field. Algorithm is not considering, it seems.

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/325434/setting-buffer-from-geoprocessingtools-with-a-feature

Comment: I think you are just passing it the field index (`num` variable) of the field `vlp1_num` as the `VALUE` argument, rather than any value in that field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pass the index number of the field when using `num`. Just use `QgsProperty.fromExpression('"vlp1_num"')` for parameter `'VALUE'`.